# iDRACView on PowerEdge M915 fails to start

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, drac

I have an M1000e enclosure with eight M915 blades. Hardware was recently unboxed and all settings are default. All nodes have iDRAC6 v3.65(Build 6) and seven of them are accessible through iDRACView java application, which is being download from the server each time I press "Launch remote console". But one of them (which is in the 4th server slot) shows "Unable to launch the application" window immediately after jnlp file starts. If I click "Details", it shows the following exception info:

```
JNLParseException[ Could not parse launch file. Error at line 0.]
        at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.decode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Wrapped exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: encoding.error.not.xml
        at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLEncoding.decodeXML(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.decode(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to rollback iDRAC6 version to 3.50(Build 4), but the error didn't disappear, so I returned to 3.65.

How can I get rid of it?

Where is that XML file? Is it incorporated into jnlp file or it's being download by the application separately? What setting in iDRAC may be unparsable?

I use CentOS 7 with Firefox 31 and Oracle JRE 8u31 to browse management controller  pages and launch the idracviewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a hardware problem. We contacted the support, they replaced server motherboard and now it works fine.